# Cómo pasar funciones por parametros a un hook reactjs

Tags: reactjs, aplicación-web, programación-móvil, react-hooks, componentes

Tengo una dificultad con los hooks de reactjs. Tengo una componente hook que implementa un metodo para detectar el onchange. Ese metodo lo paso a un parametro a un hook para un input. El problema es que cuando se modifica el input no pasa nada con la función traida del componente superior (donde incrusté el hook para el input).

Esto funciona bien si los componentes fueran clases pero no logro hacerla funcionar con funciones hooks. Quien puede ilustrarme? por favor!

Comment: Bienvenido a S.O. Español, Por favor compartenos el código de lo que has intentado, [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Bienvenido te recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que ganes tu primera medalla . Por favor, añade el código de lo que has hecho **editando** tu pregunta, si no tienes ni idea de como hacer,  [la documentación](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) siempre es tu mejor amiga.